# The most effective way to organize info on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The data structure I want to store on pandas dataframe can be represented as following:

```
        F1    F2     F3 . . . .

a
b
c
t1
t2
.
.
t18000
x1
x2
.
.
x18000
y
z
```

When i want to visualize the rows just to have an insight what information the dataframe includes, I don't wanna see 18000 t or x variables. Instead I want to sth like: [a,b,c,t,x,y,z]

I am not really familiar with Pandas module, so my question is how should I store the information to reach the row names as I indicated above in the future? More specifically:

- Should I store t and x values as array in one cell?

  ```
               F1                F2        ...
  a
  b
  c
  t [t1 t2 .. t18000]
  x [x1 x2 .. x18000]
  y
  z
  ```
- Or is there an inherent way to visualize multiple indices of the same name of rows as one in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. You could use a [Multiindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html), which lets you create a hierarchical index. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'F1': range(4)}, index=[['x', 'x', 'y', 'y'], ['x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'y2']])
```

will give you a DataFrame like:

```
        F1
x   x1  0
    x2  1
y   y1  2
    y2  3
```

You can simply `groupby` level, e.g. to sum, `df.groupby(level=0).sum()`

Alternatively, if you don't want to have an index, you can just use a function in `groupby`. For example to group by the first character in the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'F1': range(4)}, index=['x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'y2'])
df.groupby(lambda index: index[0]).sum()
```